# wso2 is 5.1.0 missing classes when running as a service (org.apache.jsp.user.edit_002duser_002droles_jsp)

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Upgrading from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 SP1 to WSO2 IS 5.1.1 patch 92 (Windows Server 2008, JRE 1.7), running as a Windows service (installed using the yajsw.conf).

Adding a role to the user fails (with a blank page), in the wso2carbon.log we have an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   
org.apache.jsp.user.edit_002duser_002droles_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
```

Interesting on it is, that running the WSO2 IS 5.1.0 from the console works (wso2server.bat) without any issues. I searched for the edit-user-roles.jsp file and I found it in the library **org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui_5.0.7.jar** (repository/components/plugins and repository/components/patches/patch0000). So - looks like the library is not loaded properly.

I was comparing the JVM settings between the IS started as a service and from CLI. The only discrepancy I found is in the **-Dcomponents.repo** parameter:

- wso2server.bat: -Dcomponents.repo=%CARBON_HOME%\repository\components
- wrapper.conf: -Dcomponents.repo=%CARBON_HOME%\repository\components\dropins

However

- in the WSO2 IS 5.0.0S.P1 it looks the same (there are different values in the wso2server.bat and wrapper.conf) and there's no problem to add a role to the user account
- I've changed the wrapper.conf to have the same value (=%CARBON_HOME%\repository\components) with no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following updates to the wrapper.conf solved the problem:

```
wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dcomponents.repo=${carbon_home}\\repository\\components
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```